# Find largest rectangle in grid that rests on border and contains point

Tags: algorithm, grid, rectangles

I have code that traverses a grid of free and "blocked" positions; and finds the largest possible rectangle.

This works just fine. However, I need to be able to find rectangle with more specific critera. Consider the following:

```
00X0000000
000000####
##########
####000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

In this diagram; 0 marks available positions, # marks occupied positions, and X marks a desired point.

The code I have now will find the bottom-right area of the grid, as that is truly the largest rectangle. However, the answer I want contains the X position (the top left rectangle).

I do not know how to go about adding this extra criteria. I tried to also keep track of coordinates; throwing out results that did not contain X; but this did not work all the time. Under certain conditions, I would get rectangles that were smaller than desired (probably because of the order I was traversing the grid)

All of the algorithms I have found seem to only capable of finding the largest rectangle, and the coordinates of the rectangle. I have not been able to find any that would be able to exclude results that do not contain a specific point reliably.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, and/or provide an implementation?

**EDIT**:
   Since comments cannot have newlines, I need to use this area to explain problems with shole's implementation. It fails for cases such as these:

```
#0#X
###0
#000
####
0#00
0000
0000
```

In the above example, the coordinates returned form a rect like this:

```
0#X
##0
000
```

answer should have been 1x3, not 3x3

Another example of failure:

```
0#X#
0000
00##
000#
0000
```

returns:

```
#X
00
```

In this case the answer returned should have been a 1x2 area, instead it thinks it is 2x2.

In some cases, it returns areas that are larger than the area of the entire grid, with coordinates outside of the range of valid coords.

This works SOMETIMES, but it is more often incorrect than it is correct. It does always return an area that contains the point though; just the wrong area/coords.

Comment: Aren't the bottom two lines the largest rectangle ? The 'area' is 20 (number of zeroes). The bottom right has area 18.

Comment: You are correct. I was eyeballing it. The general idea though is that I don't want to return any of the bottom rectangles, just the one that has the X point in it.

Comment: You can start from X and go up, down, left and right (like a ripple) and expand until you get a '#'. The coordinates near the hash will be one of the end-points of such a maximal rectangle.

Comment: @user1952500 no...actually the end-points of the answer may not be near any hash...in OP's example, point (1,6) is a point of the answer but no where near hash...

Comment: @shole, I said that the _coordinates near the hash will be one of the end-points_, not the other way around. The rectangle which is the answer to the above will have the bottom-right corner next to a hash.

Comment: @user1952500 oh sorry that i misunderstand...still a bit confused though, can you illustrate how to find the answer of this with your method? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ejQ5C.jpg

Comment: @shole: start from X and try going up, down, left and right. Do the same for each such point obtained until you get a hash. For the example you mention, the coordinates of the end-points are (assuming top left is (0,0)):
{(0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 6), (3, 0), (3, 6), (4, 2), (4, 4), (some more for other #s) }. Basically we are getting a polygon that encompasses X. The rectangle will be contained in this polygon. 
To get the individual corners, we could brute-force the above, but there are likely better ways to do it than that.

Comment: @user984444 is my answer unclear? Or does it solve your problem actually? :)

Comment: @shole Thank you for the answer. I admit I have no tested it yet, as I have moved on to other areas of my game. =X. It looks promising, but I am concerned about the speed of the algorithm; although that may not matter as I am working with rather small grids.

Comment: @user984444 Thanks for the reply :D ! I was just worrying if the explain is unclear as the concept of the DP is not that obvious. For performance I think it is almost the best you can get for easy implementation, O(size of grid), if size of grid is < 10^9, it can finish within 1 second. Also O(size of grid) is equal to the I/O time, it cannot be better than it if you include I/O.  Lastly "Largest Empty Rectangle" is a quite well known problem, while "containing point" is just some limit which can be done in O(1) as I show (add offset, minus offset)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem, here is my O(R*C) algorithm with R = # rows, C = #columns

The idea is simple, brute force every point as potential rectangles' bottom border, then try to climb up as high as possible to obtain maximum height, then get the largest left and right distance of this vertical line

[image]

This tests all potential rectangles, but we have to do it fast.
We do it by dynamic programming, row by row, for each (i,j), calculating the maximum height, maximum left and right distance it can reach.

Then we can test if X is inside this potential rectangle, if yes, I add a **infinite large offset** to the area of this rectangle, it is large enough that any rectangle DOES NOT contains X will be smaller than it, while other rectangles, if contains X and larger than it, we still can choose that rectangle instead.

After the end of the algorithm, we get the maximum **Area + Offset**, we subtract the offset from it and get the area back.

It's more easy to understand if you run the code (C++) and see the log below, with following input:

```
6 10
00X0000000
000000####
##########
####000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char w[20][20];
int tl[20][20] = {0}, tr[20][20] = {0}, h[20][20] = {0}, l[20][20]={0}, r[20][20]={0};
int ans, R,C, xr,xc, ar1, ac1, ar2, ac2; 

int largestRect()
{
    int area = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<20;i++) for(int j=0; j<20;j++) l[i][j] = r[i][j] = 1<<28;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=R;i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=C;j++)
         if(w[i][j]!='#') tl[i][j] = tl[i][j-1]+1;
      else tl[i][j] = 0;
 
     for(int j=C; j>=1; j--)
      if(w[i][j]!='#') tr[i][j] = tr[i][j+1]+1;
      else tr[i][j] = 0;
     
     for(int j=1; j<=C; j++)
      if(w[i][j]!='#') h[i][j] = h[i-1][j]+1;
      else h[i][j] = 0;
     
     for(int j=1; j<=C; j++)
      if(w[i][j] != '#') l[i][j] = min(tl[i][j], l[i-1][j]);
     
     for(int j=1; j<=C; j++)
      if(w[i][j] != '#') r[i][j] = min(tr[i][j], r[i-1][j]);
    
     
     for(int j=1; j<=C;j++){
      int offset = 0;
      if((r[i][j]+l[i][j]-1)*h[i][j] > 0){
          if(xr >= i-h[i][j]+1 && xr <= i && xc >= j-l[i][j]+1 && xc <= j+r[i][j]-1) offset = 1<<28;
       printf("Top left = (%d,%d)  Bottom right = (%d,%d)\n", i-h[i][j]+1, j-l[i][j]+1,i, j+r[i][j]-1);
       printf("Area = %d\n", (r[i][j]+l[i][j]-1)*h[i][j]);
       printf("Included X? %d\n", xr >= i-h[i][j]+1 && xr <= i && xc >= j-l[i][j]+1 && xc <= j+r[i][j]-1 );
       printf("Area with offset = %d\n\n", (r[i][j]+l[i][j]-1)*h[i][j] + offset);
        
       if(area <= (r[i][j]+l[i][j]-1)*h[i][j] + offset){
        area = max(area, (r[i][j]+l[i][j]-1)*h[i][j] + offset);
         ar1 = i-h[i][j]+1; ac1 = j-l[i][j]+1; ar2 = i; ac2 = j+r[i][j]-1;
       }
      }
     }
    }
   
    return area;
}

int main(){
 scanf("%d %d", &R, &C);
 
 for(int i=0; i<20;i++) for(int j=0; j<20;j++) w[i][j] = '#';
 
 for(int i=1; i<=R; i++){
  getchar();
  for(int j=1; j<=C; j++){
   w[i][j] = getchar(); 
   if(w[i][j] == 'X'){ xr = i; xc = j;}
  } 
 }
 
 ans = largestRect() - (1<<28);

 printf("Largest Rect Containing X is (%d,%d) to (%d,%d), with area = %d\n", ar1, ac1, ar2, ac2, ans);
 return 0; 
}
```

**EDITED PART: Algorithm / Code Explained in Details**

First thing first, here is the outline of our O(R*C) algorithm:

1. Brute force every **empty point** in grid, use it as a point of bottom border of our potential largest empty rectangle. It's O(R*C)
2. For each point, I want to go upwards as far as possible, let's define **h[i][j]** be the array meaning the highest height you can reach starting at (i,j)
3. Now I want to know how far I can go left and right, **within this vertical segment range**
4. I get a height, I get the longest length of right and left I can reach within this height, so I can of course calculate this rectangle's area
5. Get the maximum of all rectangle's area repeating step 1-4

Then we will see how to do step 2-3 in the algorithm, we will use **Dynamic Programming**.

Let's define several array:

```
h[i][j] := the highest height you can reach starting at (i,j)
tr[i][j] := the longest distance to right you can reach starting at (i,j)
tl[i][j] := the longest distance to left you can reach starting at (i,j)
```

One should be able to see these three arrays can be **precompute using O(R*C)**

```
h[i][j] = h[i-1][j]+1  if(i,j) is empty, else h[i][j] = 0
similarly
tr[i][j] = tr[i][j+1]+1 if(i,j) is empty, else tr[i][j] = 0
tl[i][j] = tl[i][j-1]+1 if(i,j) is empty, else tl[i][j] = 0
```

Now we define two more arrays

```
l[i][j] := the longest distance to right you can reach starting from 
line (i,j) and (i-h[i][j]+1,j) (That's simply just put h[i][j] into consideration)
```

Similar to r[i][j], please make sure you understand the difference between tl[i][j] and l[i][j] (tr[i][j] and r[i][j])

Now l[i][j] and r[i][j] can also be precomputed using O(R*C)!

A little difference is that they need h[i][j] and tr[i][j] (or tl[i][j]) to compute it,

so h[i][j], tl[i][j], tr[i][j] must be computed before l[i][j] and r[i][j].

```
l[i][j] = min(l[i-1][j], tl[i][j]) if(i,j) is empty, else l[i][j] = tl[i][j]
r[i][j] = min(r[i-1][j], tr[i][j]) if(i,j) is empty, else r[i][j] = tr[i][j]
```

> You can think that it is saying the following statements:
>
> l[i][j] is the **minimum tl[X][j]**, X within [i-h[i][j]+1, i]
>
> So l[i][j] is the maximum distance to left within (i,j) to its maximum height

Similar to r[i][j]

So my code is using two for loops doing exactly the Dynamic Programming described above, it's seems complicated because **I did not precompute them all before using them**

I compute these arrays and use them to calculate the rectangle's area **on the fly**. Being said, you can always precompute all of these arrays first, then calculate the maximum areas afterwards, the time complexity is still O(R*C)

Comment: I tried to convert this to C# (the language required for my project), but I realized I don't understand this code.Why are all of those arrays 20x20, when the input is 6x10? Why are the l and r arrays initialized to such high values, but not tr and tl? Is this just a C++ thing, and the extra elements are not even used?

Comment: does it work though? and which part you do not understand? I try to explain more, it's hard to understand at first glance because there is some clever DP concept behind it

Comment: I don't know yet because I haven't finished the conversion. Haha. Going through this line by line, I think there may be a bug when assigning r[i][j]. Shouldn't that loop be going in the opposite direction?

Comment: no...you may mixed up r[i][j] with tr[i][j], tr[i][j] has to be in reverse direction , l[i][j] and r[i][j] needs not, maybe I add an explanation in my answer now :)

Comment: Please try to see the edited part to see if you can understand the algorithm and code more :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, this is not working. I get results outside of the grid bounds, and negative areas. It gives strange results at other times. The commenting system here makes it impossible for me to show you unfortunately. Going to edit my question to explain

Comment: @user984444 Just saw your edited part, and thanks, that's a bug that totally not related to the algorithm: Please change ans = largestRect() - 1<<28; to ans = largestRect() - (1<<28);

Comment: I actually had to remove the subtraction of 1<<28 altogether, as the areas made zero sense (numbers like -2.684354E+08 for area being reported)

Comment: @user984444 can u tell me an example that gives such strange area, using my C++ code? (you can run on ideone.com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75445/discussion-between-shole-and-user984444).