# Maximum complete table in incomplete table

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an (efficient) algorithm that computes the largest complete table in a table with missing cells. So for example:
In

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e | f |  | h |

is the maximum complete table

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| e | f |

Optional: It would be great if one could adjust the measure. So for example instead of counting cells, the number of rows and/or columns would be important.

Comment: Hi! Maybe those questions can help you: [Find largest rectangle contain only 1s in the grid with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069963/find-largest-rectangle-contain-only-1s-in-the-grid-with-python): [Find largest rectangle containing only zeros in an N×N binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%c3%97n-binary-matrix); [Find largest rectangle in grid that rests on border and contains point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612185/find-largest-rectangle-in-grid-that-rests-on-border-and-contains-point).

Comment: @Stef this seems even more trivial since a "table" must include its headers.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You might be overinterpreting the given example; I suspect the OP made a,b,c,d headers by mistake. Or maybe I am the one interpreting wrongly. A clarification from JannisH would be welcome.

Comment: The header does not need to be included, I just did not know how to change it.